# Removing multiple from a select list

Tags: jquery

I have a select list:

```
<select name="taxonomy[1][]" multiple="multiple" class="form-select" id="edit-taxonomy-1" size="7">
     <option value="0">None</option>
    <option value="13">Glaciers</option>
    <option value="14">Lake Ice</option>
    <option value="17">Permafrost</option>
    <option value="16">River Ice</option>
    <option value="15">Sea Ice</option>
    <option value="12">Snow</option>
</select>
```

How do I use jquery to remove the multiple="mutiple" from the select so that it is just

```
<select name="taxonomy[1][]" class="form-select" id="edit-taxonomy-1" size="7">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#edit-taxonomy-1").removeAttr( 'multiple' );
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

On jQuery site: [removeAttr](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

```
$("#edit-taxonomy-1").removeAttr("multiple");
```

> Description: Remove an attribute from each element in the set of matched elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#edit-taxonomy-1").removeAttr("multiple");
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.removeAttr()`

like in your case it should be `$("#edit-taxonomy-1").removeAttr("multiple");`